# Manipulação de tabelas temporárias sql em delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-4

Boa tarde
Crio no Delphi uma tabela temporária Sql, ou seja, ela não existe fisicamente.
Consigo ate gravar dados nela, mas não consigo colocar as informações em um dbgrid:

1) Crei a tabela assim:

```
qryCIDtemp.SQL.add('Create table ''#tempCiD''(SUS varchar(50), Saude varchar(50), Diferenca varchar(30), dtCompetencia char(6)');  //Cria tabela temporária
qryCIDtemp.Close;
qryCIDtemp.sql.clear;// limpa conteúdo do dataset

qryCIDtemp.sql.Add('Insert into ''#tempcid''(SUS,Sanitas,Diferenca,dtCompetencia)');
qryCIDtemp.sql.Add('values (:SUS,:Saude,:Diferenca,:dtCompetencia)');
```

2)gravei dentro de while not eof..., só uma parte do código aqui para vocês entenderem:

```
qryCiDtemp.ParamByname('SuS').value    := qryCidProcedimentoBKP.FieldByName('cdcid10').AsString ;
qryCIDtemp.ParamByname('Saude').value:= qryCid.FieldByName('cdcid10').AsString ;
qryCIDtemp.ParamByname('Diferenca').value:= 'CID';
```

3) Não sei se  era necessário mas usei mas o seguinte comando:

```
qryCIDtemp.SQL.add('Select * from ''#tempCID''');
```

4) Só depois disto tentei mostrar o resultado no dbgrid utilizando o código:
obs.: o dbgrid esta sem datasource

```
with qryCIDtemp do
       begin
            dbgrid2.Columns.Clear;
            dbgrid2.Columns.Add;
            dbgrid2.Columns[0].FieldName :='sus';
            dbgrid2.Columns[0].Title.Caption := 'Informação SUS';
            dbgrid2.Columns[0].Width := 500;
            dbgrid2.Columns.Add;
            dbgrid2.Columns[1].FieldName := 'SAuDE';
            dbgrid2.Columns[1].Title.Caption := 'Informação Saúde';
            dbgrid2.Columns[1].Width := 500;
            dbgrid2.Columns.Add;
            dbgrid2.Columns[2].FieldName := 'Diferença';
            dbgrid2.Columns[2].Title.Caption := 'Diferença';
            dbgrid2.Columns[2].Width := 200;
       end;
```

o dbgrid chega a mostrar os caption´s preencidos e os width corretamente, mas esta vazio.

no form tenho uma query com nome qryCIDtemp, na proppriende string não tem nenhuma sentença SQL. Tem um DaSource ligado a qryCIDtemp

A propriedade DataSource da qryCIDtemp esta vazia, tenho que colocar alguma informação aqui? Como é temporária não sei o que preencher.

Se alguém puder me ajudar fico muito grata

Comment: Qual a sua versão do delphi?

Comment: Para usar o DBGrid basta fazer a ligação com o Datasource.

Answer (score 0):

As querys do delphi apenas fazem conexão direta com o banco de dados elas não armazenam dados temporários.

Para fazer o que deseja utilize o TClientDataSet (Delphi 7) ou o TFDMemTable (Delphi XE5+)

No caso você não vai tratar com creates e inserts, você faria +/- assim

```
oMemTable.Append;
oMemTable.FieldByName('Saude').value     := qryCid.FieldByName('cdcid10').AsString ;
oMemTable.FieldByName('Diferenca').value := 'CID';
oMemTable.Post;
```

Ai sim depois quando quiser salvar no banco, você faz um laço nesse oMemTable e vai gravando cada registro.

Comment: Utilizo o SQL Server 2000 e o Delphi 4, não fiz a mudança que você sugeriu ainda por agora, inseri uma linha de código

Comment: Vish Delphi 4... Bom nunca usei essa versão, mas deve existir o ClientDataSet nele também. Não entendi o que você quis dizer com _"não fiz a mudança que você sugeriu ainda por agora, inseri uma linha de código"_

Answer (score 0):

Na palheta Data Access da Tool Palette procure pelo TClientDataSet, ele possui recursos para realizar exatamente o que precisa..pois ele consegue salvar em memória sua tabela temporária e te possibilita obter esses registros logo após.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de preencher os parâmetros, mas antes de consultar os dados, você tem que chamar o método ExecSQL para que o sistema execute o INSERT no banco de dados:

```
// preenche os parâmetros
qryCiDtemp.ParamByname('SuS').value := qryCidProcedimentoBKP.FieldByName('cdcid10').AsString;
qryCIDtemp.ParamByname('Saude').value:= qryCid.FieldByName('cdcid10').AsString;
qryCIDtemp.ParamByname('Diferenca').value:= 'CID';

// executa o comando contido em qryCiDtemp.SQL no banco de dados
qryCiDtemp.ExecSQL;

// consulta os dados do banco
qryCIDtemp.SQL.add('Select * from ''#tempCID''');
```

Answer (score 0):

É justamente porque faltou o datasource.  O DBGrid é um controle DBWare.

Ligue um datasource no DBGrid, e ligue sua query no datasource que deverá funcionar.